# *Need help solving my program* Visual Studio debugging error

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

The output comes with a debugging error which says:

```
Runtime check failure #3 - The variable 'GPE2' is being used without being initialized.
```

I entered the mass & height of the object as `5kg,5m` for `GPE1` and `5kg,6m` for `GPE2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define g 9.81

void main(void)
{
    // step 1: variable declaration
    float GPE1, GPE2, h;
    int m;
    // step 2: input
    printf("Mr Lim: The higher the object, the greater the Gravitational Potential Energy. \n");
    printf("Let me prove it to you with this simple physics question! \n\n");
    printf("An object is located at the surface of the earth. \n");
    printf("Calculate the Gravitational Potential Energy (in J) the body possesses. \n\n\n");
    printf("Enter the mass of the body (in kg): ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter the height of the body (in m): ");
    scanf("%f", &h);

    if (h > 0) {
        // step 3: calculation
        GPE1 = m * g * h;
        // step 4: output
        printf("The Gravitational Potential Energy, GPE (in J) = %.2f joules. \n\n", GPE1);
    }
    else {
        printf("The Gravitational Potential Energy is undefined! \n");
    }

    printf("Mr Lim: Now, to prove my statement is valid \n");
    printf("Find the GPE a body possesses, when its height is greater. \n");
    printf("Enter the mass of the body (in kg): ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter the height of the body (in m): ");
    scanf("%f", &h);

    if (GPE2 > GPE1) {
        GPE2 = m * g * h;
        printf("The Gravitational Potential Energy, GPE (in J) = %.2f joules. \n\n", GPE2);
        printf("Mr Lim: See class, I told you! \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Class is not impressed. \n");
        printf("Mr Lim should retire! \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see any assignments to `GPE2` before `if (GPE2 > GPE1)`

Comment: so how do I assign GPE2 and get the 'if' output instead of the 'else' output? Really urgent as I have to submit this tmrw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error statement is true. You are checking if `GPE2 > GPE1` in your if statement and then initializing GPE2.

You could add a statement just above the if statement that said `GPE2 = 0;`
Or initialize it when you declare it at the top of the program. Right now it holds whatever garbage happened to be at the memory location before.

Comment: ur solution sorta helped me get the program to run but I got the ELSE output as:  printf("Class is not impressed. \n");
  printf("Mr Lim should retire! \n"); instead of the printf("The Gravitational Potential Energy, GPE (in J) = %.2f joules. \n\n", GPE2);
  printf("Mr Lim: See class, I told you! \n");               I need to get the latter output. Can you help me out with it?

Comment: Yes, that is because your logic is off. You are still not assigning to GPE2 until after the `if(GPE2 > GPE1)` statement. For that you could move the assignment to GPE2 above the `if` statement:

`GPE2 = m*g*h;`
`if (GPE2 > GPE1)`
`{ `
`....`
`}`

Comment: WOW THANKS MAN THE SOLUTION REALLY HELPED ME SOLVE THE QUESTION. Kudos to you James all the way from Singapore.

Answer (score 0):

You declare GPE2, but you not init value for it, it will get random value. So, when you compare it with GPE1, you will get the warning, and your code will run with wrong logic.